# perl creates unexplained file called "1"

Tags: perl, sorting, file-io, io

I have been trying to get rid of a weird bug for hours, with no success. I have a subroutine that sorts a file. here is the code:

```
sub sort_file {
  $filename = @_;

  print @_;
  print $filename;

  open(SRTINFILE,"<$filename");
  @lines=<SRTINFILE>;
  close(SRTINFILE);

  open(SRTOUTFILE,">$filename");
  @sorted = sort { @aa=split(/ /,$a); @bb=split(/ /,$b); return ($aa[1] <=> $bb[1]); } @lines;
  print SRTOUTFILE @sorted;

  close(SRTOUTFILE);

}
```

any time this function is run, perl creates a file, called "1". i have no idea why. I am a complete perl noob and am just using it for quick and dirty text file processing. anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers are sufficient to tell you why you were getting strange errors.

I would like to show you how a more experienced Perl programmer might write this subroutine.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;

sub sort_file {
  my( $filename ) = @_;

  my @lines;
  {
    # 3 arg open
    open my $in_fh, '<', $filename;
    @lines = <$in_fh>;
    close $in_fh;
  }

  # Schwartzian transform
  my @sorted = map{
    $_->[0]
  } sort {
    $a->[2] <=> $b->[2]
  } map {
    [ $_, split ' ', $_ ]
  } @lines;

  {
    open my $out_fh, '>', $filename;
    print {$out_fh} @sorted;
    close $out_fh;  
  }
}
```

- `use strict;`
  prevents you from using a variable without declaring it (among other things).
- `use warnings;`
  Informs you of some potential errors.
- `use autodie;`
  Now you don't need to write `open .... or die ....`
- `{ open ...; @lines = <$fh>; close $fh }`
  Limits the scope of the FileHandle.
- `@sorted = map { ... } sort { ... } map { ... } @list`
  This is an examples of a [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), which reduces the number of times that the values are split. In this example, it may be overkill.

Answer (score 10):

An array in scalar context evalutes to the number of elements in the array. If you pass one argument to the function, the following assigns `1` to `$filename`.

```
$filename = @_;
```

You want any of the following:

```
$filename = $_[0];
$filename = shift;
($filename) = @_;
```

Furthermore, you want to limit the scope of the variable to the function, so you want

```
my $filename = $_[0];
my $filename = shift;
my ($filename) = @_;
(my $filename) = @_;  # Exact same as previous.
```

Comment: ... or even `my $filename = shift`

Comment: @Brad Gilbert, Sure, but why use slower `shift` if you're not going to do something funky with `@_`. I'll add it to the answer "for fun".

Comment: I have no idea which perl versions but the (single) shift was faster in the past (not that these micro-optimizations are important). I think I saw the benchmarks on PerlMonks but it was probably two or three years ago.

Answer (score 2):

How confusing. Assigning `$filename = @_` the way you are means that you are evaluating an array in scalar context, which means that `$filename` is assigned the number of elements in `@_`. Because you don't check to see if the first `open` call succeeds, reading the file `1` likely fails, but you continue anyway and open for writing a file named `1`. The solution is to use `$filename` in an array context and begin your subroutine with `($filename) = @_` or `$filename = shift`.

Why aren't you using `use strict` by the way?

Comment: "Why aren't you using use strict by the way?" answer: because when it comes to perl, i'm a cowboy noob who hasn't even read a tutorial all the way through yet. thanks for the tip, just added that line.

Answer (score 1):

Always use:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Then Perl will tell you when you're off the mark.

As you've observed, the notation:

```
$filename = @_;
```

means that an unscoped variable is assigned the number of elements in the argument list to the function, and since you pass one file, the name of the created file will be '1'.

You meant to write:

```
my($filename) = @_;
```

This provides list context for the array, and assigns `$_[0]` to `$filename`, ignoring any extra arguments to the function.

Answer (score -1):

OK... nevermind. it just dawned on me. `$filename = @_;` makes no sense. should be `$filename = @_[0];` . There goes 2 hours of my life. note to other perl noobs: beware.

Comment: My answer has some alternatives. TMTOWTDI :)

Comment: Please use `use strict; use warnings;` in your code. It will save far more than 2 hours of your life.

Comment: haha. thanks, mkb. i submitted that before i saw your answer. point taken, perl seems to have tons of ways of doing anything. i like :D

Comment: `@_[0]` is also wrong. See the other answers for the correct way to do it.